# While parsing PHP source code, Doxygen treats "$" as a type rather than the variable token

Tags: php, doxygen

For instance:

```
/** \file test.php
 * this is test.php file
 */

/** 
 * This is foo
 * @param $myPar
 */
function foo($myPar) {

}
```

Doxygen generates something like:

```
<td class="paramtype">
 $
</td>

<td class="paramname">
<em> myPar </em>
</td>
```

Why? It seems like Doxygen is using another parser rather than the PHP one.

Comment: which version do you use? which settings and etc?

Comment: Hi, Doxygen 1.7.1. Settings are the defaults plus "EXTRACT_ALL=YES"

Comment: try to disable it. See "If the EXTRACT_ALL tag is set to YES doxygen will assume all entities in documentation are documented, even if no documentation was available."

Comment: The problem is still there. I disabled ETRACT_ALL and than I documented the PHP file with \file comment and then each function with \param. Doxygen produces a page with a section "Function Documentation" where each function has $ and the variable name splitted in two different HTML table columns. Incredible!

Comment: May be it thinks, that each param MUST have type? Try to add it like @param string $myPar

Comment: Nope. I get <td>string</td><td>$</td><td>myPar</td>

Comment: Then it's seems, like doxygen treats sources as non php? Which tags do you use: long or short?

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean for short/long tags?

Comment: see "php short tags" in google

Comment: As far as I know Doxygen selects the parser to use checking the file exstention, ".php" in this case. Hence PHP tags have nothing to do. However I chacked it out and actually you can completely remove the tags: Doxygen works in the same way and produces the same strange output.

Answer (score 0):

It's seems, like you found bug in Doxygen PHP parser. I tried same with both XML and HTML output -- in both cases param type was determined wrong.

```
<?php
/** 
 * This is foo
 * @param $myPar
 */
function foo($myPar) {

}

function bar($myPar) {

}

function hi(ArrayIterator $myPar) {

}
```

My version:

```
ustimenko@home:/tmp/doxy$ doxygen --version
1.7.6.1
```

Also ETRACT_ALL = YES, as in opposite case it not extracts those functions.

Comment: Thank you gaRex. The right discussion, I guess, is this one  https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=679974

Comment: Yes it is. And he is still waiting for patch. SVN must die. All go to github :)